# Problema com substring

Tags: javascript

Fiz essa função para apagar o resultado da tabuada e apagar o que esta dentro do meu input de números. Porém quando eu uso o botão de apagar, o número que está no input de numero não é apagado, na verdade o meu botão de apagar nem funciona. Alguém sabe o por que disso?

```
function apagar(){
    var num = document.getElementById('num')
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    if(num.value.length != 0){
        num.substring(0, num.value.length-1);
    }
    if (res.textContent != 0){
        res.innerHTML = ``
    } else if(res.textContent == 0){
        alert('Gere uma tabuada primeiro!')
    }
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `num.substring` deveria ser `num.value.substring`. Mas ainda sim teria que atribuir o retorno a alguma variável, pois `substring` retorna outra string (ele não altera a string original)

Comment: Se não me engano, se fizer `document.getElementById('num').value = ''` ele deveria retornar o `input` num como vazio

Answer (score -2):

O substring não é bom para esse tipo de situação já que o propósito ele é retornar parte de uma string.

Para limpar todos os dados do input, existe uma função chamada reset() que limpa todos os dados do formulário.

```
function apagar(){

  const myform = document.getElementById('myform');
  const resposta = document.getElementById('res');
  
  /* Esta forma de utilizar o if se chama Guard Clause */
  if(!myform) return;
  if(!resposta) {
    alert('Gere uma tabuada primeiro!');
    return
  }

  myform.reset();
  resposta.innerHtml = '' 
}
```

Se você não estiver utilizando a tag , pode utilizar a propriedade `value` do input.

```
function apagar(){

  const numero = document.getElementById('num');
  const resposta = document.getElementById('res');
  
  /* Esta forma de utilizar o if se chama Guard Clause */
  if(!numero) return;
  if(!resposta) {
    alert('Gere uma tabuada primeiro!');
    return
  }

  numero.value = '';
  resposta.innerHtml = '' 
}
```